# R Replace row values to the other rows based on/condition on column information in one data set?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, grouping

I received a flat data, and the values were missing while flatting data. 
I have to bring the hours up to NAs in hours, based on id, type and Date, so that remove NAs in dollars

```
id<-c(1,2,1,1,1,2,1)
dollar<-as.numeric(c(100,200,300,500, NA, NA,NA))
hours<-as.numeric(c(NA,NA, NA, NA, 5,10,12))
type<-c("Engineer", "Engineer","Operating","Part", "Engineer","Engineer","Operating" )
Date<-c("2020-01-02","2020-01-03","2020-01-02","2020-01-04", "2020-01-02","2020-01-03","2020-01-02")

  id dollar hours      type       Date
1  1    100  <NA>  Engineer 2020-01-02
2  2    200  <NA>  Engineer 2020-01-03
3  1    300  <NA> Operating 2020-01-02
4  1    500  <NA>      Part 2020-01-04
5  1   <NA>     5  Engineer 2020-01-02
6  2   <NA>    10  Engineer 2020-01-03
7  1   <NA>    12 Operating 2020-01-02
```

and I would like to reform my data as below.

```
  id dollar hours      type       Date
1   1     100      5  Engineer 2020-01-02
2   2     200     10  Engineer 2020-01-03
3   1     300     12 Operating 2020-01-02
4   1     500   <NA>      Part 2020-01-04
```

It is not just grouped by id, but matches with type and date.
'id' has categories, 'type' has 17 categories and 'Date' are 3 years.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach with `tidyverse`. You can group by `id`, `type`, and `date` and then fill missing NA with available values.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(id, type, Date) %>%
  fill(c(dollar, hours), .direction = "updown") %>%
  slice(1)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   id, type, Date [4]
     id dollar hours type      Date      
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <fct>     <fct>     
1     1    100     5 Engineer  2020-01-02
2     1    300    12 Operating 2020-01-02
3     1    500    NA Part      2020-01-04
4     2    200    10 Engineer  2020-01-03
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a `dplyr` option using `summarise`

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(id, type, Date) %>%
    summarise_at(vars(dollar, hours), ~mean(.x, na.rm = T))
## A tibble: 4 x 5
## Groups:   id, type [4]
#     id type      Date       dollar hours
#  <dbl> <fct>     <fct>       <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 Engineer  2020-01-02    100     5
#2     1 Operating 2020-01-02    300    12
#3     1 Part      2020-01-04    500   NaN
#4     2 Engineer  2020-01-03    200    10
```

Or even

```r
df %>% group_by(id, type, Date) %>% summarise_all(~mean(.x, na.rm = T))
```

---

### Sample data

```r
df <- data.frame(id, dollar, hours, type, Date)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` function from `tidyr` to reshape your dataset into a longer format, remove NA values and then reshape into a wider format:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(dollar, hours), names_to = "var", values_to = "val") %>%
  filter(!is.na(val)) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = var, values_from = val)

# A tibble: 4 x 5
     id type      Date       dollar hours
  <dbl> <fct>     <fct>       <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 Engineer  2020-01-02    100     5
2     2 Engineer  2020-01-03    200    10
3     1 Operating 2020-01-02    300    12
4     1 Part      2020-01-04    500    NA
```